# shouldComponentUpdate() returns true but NavLink still doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, jsx, react-router-v4

I recently tried implementing a navlink like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import '../css/navbar.css';
import logoWhite from '../../common/images';

const Navbar = props => {
    return (
        <div id="navbar" className="grid">
            <Link to="/" className="column logo-container">
                <img src={logoWhite} alt="Test logo" />
            </Link>

            <ul className="column navigation">
                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/" exact className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <NavLink to="/match" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Partner Proposals</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Upon running I encountered the issue of the classname not being passed to the navlink when the route changed. Reading on articles and it led me to suspect that the `shouldComponentUpdate` method was being rendered `false`. So, I rewrote the `Navbar` like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import '../css/navbar.css';
import logoWhite from '../../common/images';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        console.log('Console log activated');
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="navbar" className="grid">
                <Link to="/" className="column logo-container">
                    <img src={logoWhite} alt="Test image" />
                </Link>

                <ul className="column navigation">
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/" exact activeClassName="active" className="nav-link">Home</NavLink>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/match" activeClassName="active" className="nav-link">Partner Proposals</NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

What's strange is that the `componentDidUpdate` returned the value in the console (suggesting that it returned true), but the NavLink was still not passing the `activeClassName`

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking why the class specified in `activeClassName` is not being applied when the route is active, correct? And to make sure, you are aware that your second snippet doesn't actually use `activeClassName`, right?

Comment: The class specified is not being applied; yes, that's the question I asked. But I made a typo in the second snippet

Comment: Try isActive(), shown in the given link and test what is happeing - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#isactive-func

Comment: you may change the "active" class name to "is_active" or something else and styled the class name (say: font-weight: bold).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from @mindaJalaj, I passed a `pathname` prop (which was rendering and re-rendering whenever there was a update to the route from the parent component), and I implemented the Navbar as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import '../css/navbar.css';
import logo from '../../common/images/logo.png';
import navLinks from '../navLinks';

const Navbar = props => {
    function renderNavLinks() {
        return navLinks.map((navLink, index) => {
            const key: string = `nav-link-${navLink.path}-${index}`;
            const exact: boolean = navLink.exact || false;

            return (
                <li key={key}>
                    <NavLink
                        to={navLink.path}
                        exact={exact}
                        className="nav-link"
                        isActive={() => navLink.path === props.pathname}
                        activeClassName="active"
                    >
                        <Icon name={navLink.icon} />
                        <span>{navLink.title}</span>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    return (
        <div id="navbar" className="grid">
            <Link to="/" className="column logo-container">
                <img src={logo} alt="Test logo" />
            </Link>

            <ul className="column navigation">{renderNavLinks()}</ul>
        </div>
    );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
    pathname: PropTypes.string
};

Navbar.defaultProps = {
    pathname: '/'
};

export default Navbar;
```